# Parse an object from MVC controller to view C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am storing an object from a list to a local variable and trying to pass it to a view like below:

```
 public class BedController : Controller
{
    // GET: Bed
    public ActionResult Index(PatientRegister model, int id)
    {
        var patient = PatientRegisterController.BedsList.Single(x => x.NewPatient.BedNumber.Equals(id.ToString()));
        return View(patient);
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to access this object from the view itself something like

```
patient.SelectSomeOfTheProperites //This is the object that I parsed from controller
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add return object type as model

```
@model Bed
```

Access the return object property as

```
@model.SelectSomeOfTheProperites
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So @Model is replacing patient object in this case?